# mapping nested object as props to custom component

Tags: json, reactjs, object, nested, jsx

I have an app where the user will search for a term and they will see the results rendered. The results, in this case, are from a nested JSON object. I have a component called `CompanyInfoList` that passes `props` to `Results` component that renders the JSX. The props are `employee`, `date`, `tax`, and `balance`. I tried to map within a map in the component, but it did not work. My goal is to get access to the details data, how do I do this. The files to look at are **CompanyInfoList** and **Results**. The data is loaded in via axios in **CompListContext**

In the `CompSearch` comp when you enter "ABC" nothing will happen, because I am not accessing the details data from the JSON obj. This is what I need help in doing.

Here is the mongo DB JSON object (pasted from PostMan):

```
"data": {
        "details": {
            "employee": "person1",
            "date": "test date",
            "tax": "test tax",
            "balance": "22"
        },
        "company": "TEST-ABC",
        "_id": "60dba9fe7641a44d40364c1f",
        "__v": 0
    }
```

[Here is my code](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-stallman-tq1tk?file=/src/TestThree/CompanyInfoList.js)

Comment: Does your linked codesandbox at least run and do anything now?

Comment: Do you have some mock response data to throw in that sandbox so there's *something* to render? The `company` array in the `CompListProvider` component is an empty array.

Comment: Looking at your code, you're calling `setCompany` with `results.data`, meaning that I was wrong on your previous question. You'd just use `details.employee` or `details.date` if you've already gone one-level deep into the object by using `results.data`. By the way, `filtered` in `CompanyInfoList` is *not* a function -- it's the result of `company.filter` in `CompSearch.js`

Comment: @jnpdx this is the error when i tried details.employee in Results comp: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'employee' of undefined`

Comment: It wouldn't be just `details.employee` -- it would be preceded by whatever variable is holding the JSON data. In `CompSearch.js`, it's `company`. In `CompanyInfoList`, it would be `filtered`, but it'll never get there because assuming the JSON you showed is what you're actually getting, the filter in `CompSearch` will fail. Like has been pointed out by Drew Reese, this might be debuggable if the sandbox worked/had mock data, but not as-is.

Comment: Are you able to get real data? That's all we need to mock up on our end. It doesn't seem your issue is getting the data, but rendering it.

Comment: the only way was a mock up JSON i made in place of the context comp i just had mock json data, yes the issue is rendering it - that is correct, i though by saying in my ques above , i cant access the deatils that was clear i could not render the data

Comment: I see, well, when I throw your example object into the `company` state and then fix the `result` value you are mapping, it renders the example object after searching for "abc". Is this all you need?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-sea-hupq1?file=/src/TestThree/CompanyInfoList.js BTW I think this is what jnpdx may've been trying to say earlier, looking back now.

Comment: Thanks, @DrewReese, that is my solution!

Comment: Sorry for all the runaround... I could see the path for what was to be rendered, but without an example object/state it wasn't clear what needed to be accessed. Glad to help get it all sorted out. 

Comment: no worries, I learned alot!, i was in the right direction but wasn't sure where to implement :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the `company` array object shape:

```
{
  details: {
    employee: "person1",
    date: "test date",
    tax: "test tax",
    balance: "22"
  },
  company: "TEST-ABC",
  _id: "60dba9fe7641a44d40364c1f",
  __v: 0
}
```

You are filtering by the element's `company` property, and when mapping the filtered results in `CompanyInfoList` you need to access the `details` property, i.e. `result.details.employee`.

```
const CompanyInfoList = ({ filtered }) => {
  const fltr = filtered.map((result) => (
    <Results
      key={result.details.id}
      employee={result.details.employee}
      date={result.details.date}
      tax={result.details.tax}
      balance={result.details.balance}
    />
  ));
  return <>{fltr}</>;
};
```

[image: Edit rough-sea-hupq1]